# The Idea of Mask

Tags: mask, cpu-architecture, nibble

[image]

I don't understand the idea of mask and why it is useful here?

Comment: In order to "select some bits, and clear others to 0".

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth where is the mask here? is it the register $t1?

Comment: i don't understand how we do that .. should i choose the mask by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposed you have a value and you want to set all bits to zero except for a few that you're interested in. So you create a *mask* which has only 1s in the positions you want to keep protected. When you use an `AND` operation with your mask that's the result you get. It appears to me that `$t1` is the value being used above as the mask.

You might be familiar with how a painter uses *masking* tape to cover an area that shouldn't be painted. It's the same kind idea.

There are basically three different operations where you'll mask bits this way: `AND` to clear bits, `OR` to set bits and `XOR` to toggle bits.

Comment: Good explanation !! Tank you